# Absolute beginner needs help, unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python

I just started using python for my studies (like two weeks ago) and I am running into some issues. I tried searching online and on this site, but I can't seem to find an answer that makes sense to me.  I'm using the code below to calculate 'MR' as a function of 'h' through the use of other functions.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def MR(p_w, p_tot):
    return (B*p_w/p_tot*p_w)

def p_w(p_ws, rh):
    return p_ws * (rh/100)

def p_ws(t):
    return A * 10**((m*t)/t+t_n)

def rh(h):
    return -0.0041*h + 60.1941

def t(h):
    return 293.15 - 0.0065*h

def p_tot(h):
    return p_b * (1 + (beta/t_0)*h)**-(g/(beta*R))

h = np.array(range(5001))
A = 6.116441
m = 7.591386
t_n = 240.7263
B = 621.9907
p_b = 101325
beta = 1.458 * 10**(-6)
t_0 = 293.15
g = 9.81
R = 287.05287

plt.plot(h, MR(p_w, p_tot))

plt.xlabel('Altitude (m)')
plt.ylabel('Mass Ratio water in air (g/kg)')

plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Which you probably already expect gives the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'

I understand what the error means, I just don't know how to fix my code.

thanks

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MR.py", line 39, in 
plt.plot(h, MR(p_w, p_tot))

File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MR.py", line 11, in MR
return (B*p_w/p_tot*p_w)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'

Comment: `MR(p_w, p_tot)` is passing `p_w` and `p_tot`, two functions, as the arguments. You mean something else there, although I'm not sure what.

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on your first question.  When posting questions about errors in Python code it's more useful if you post the *full traceback* (everything from "Traceback (most recent call last)" leading up to the error, because that will help pinpoint exactly where in your code it's coming from.  In this case it appears you are trying to multiply a numeric value by a function.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Thanks for the heads-up as well. I have added the traceback in the original post.

Comment: That traceback doesn't match the previous error, and the error message doesn't match the code that you've posted. The problem is you passing function instead of numbers to the functions, but without seeing your actual code, we can't help you beyond that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Actively trying to fix the code myself at the moment, which does not help. I have edited the post again, so that the error should match the code. I understand my intentions are not very clear through the code itself. So, I am trying to plot values of MR as a result of h. The calculation of MR is done via other formulas, which I defined as p_w, p_ws, p_tot, rh, and t. I used to perform these calculation using Matlab, which held my hand a bit more. Again, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @TbjK Could you see whether the following answer answered your need, if yes you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems your parameter is a function and function is been involved in the multiplication operation and that seems what the error. Following is fixed code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def MR(h_val):
    return (B * p_w(h_val)) / (p_tot(h_val) * p_w(h_val))


def p_w(h_val):
    return p_ws(h_val) * (rh(h_val) / 100)


def p_ws(h_val):
    return A * 10 ** ((m * t(h_val)) / t(h_val) + t_n)


def rh(h_val):
    return -0.0041 * h_val + 60.1941


def t(h_val):
    return 293.15 - 0.0065 * h_val


def p_tot(h_val):
    return p_b * (1 + (beta / t_0) * h_val) ** -(g / (beta * R))


h = np.array(range(5001))
A = 6.116441
m = 7.591386
t_n = 240.7263
B = 621.9907
p_b = 101325
beta = 1.458 * 10 ** (-6)
t_0 = 293.15
g = 9.81
R = 287.05287

plt.plot(h, MR(h))

plt.xlabel('Altitude (m)')
plt.ylabel('Mass Ratio water in air (g/kg)')

plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The error is here:

```
def MR(p_w, p_tot):
    return (B*p_w/p_tot*p_w)

def p_w(p_ws, rh):
    return p_ws * (rh/100)
```

You defined `p_w` as a function and then as a variable inside `MR`. Rename it and it may start working.

Comment: That isn't the error. `p_w` is a parameter of `MR`, and will shadow any globals. The problem is the arguments passed in, not the parameter names (although the parameters should be renamed as well to avoid confusion).